# Configuration file in react js

Tags: reactjs, configuration

Is there any way in react to pass parameters via configurations which could be change even after we compile and build react-app. That means, app should take the parameter values via configurations. (Values such as url, port number)

Answer (score 0):

you must define yourself a envirionment class

e.g.

```
export const API_URL = 'API_URL';
export const META_TITLE = 'META_TITLE';
```

Comment: is it a separate file, what is the path in folder structure

Comment: enough to 'constants' folder

`constants`
    `actionTypes.js`
    `envirionment.js`
    `routes.js`